# Intel onboard Wi-Fi repeatedly disconnects after a few minutes

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have temporary connection when I turn on the Wi-Fi. However, after a few minutes, it have no access to the Internet although the connection signal to the access point is still strong and stable. I have to turn it on and off again and again to have discrete connections. Please kindly help me with the issue. Thank you so much.

**Here is some details of the setup.**

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Alder Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 11
       serial: 8c:b8:7e:eb:5c:85
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-76-generic firmware=64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-hr-b0-64.uc ip=10.13.123.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:18 memory:601311c000-601311ffff
```

**Some warning logs from NetworkManager:**

```
<warn>  [1689661550.5818] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
<warn>  [1689661550.8298] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
<warn>  [1689661551.2288] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
<warn>  [1689676187.7033] dns-sd-resolved[2ac8957329ca15d4]: send-updates failed to update systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchL>
<warn>  [1689701627.2439] sup-iface[0x5630e8131920,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason 3)
<warn>  [1689714144.1550] sup-iface[0x5630e8131920,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
```